# EPPlus how to write actual 'true' value

Tags: epplus

Using EPPlus, how can I write the actual excel TRUE value to a cell?  I'm just getting the text value, and I have to explicitly click into the cell and press enter to have it recognize it as a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cell.Value` is an object so if you set it as a `bool` it will box it and preserve the type:

```
var cells = worksheet.Cells;
cells["A1"].Value = false;   // not = "false"
cells["A2"].Value = true;    // not = "true"
```

Which will give you this:

[image]